# How to make a data class variable optional? (Android Studio - Kotlin)

Tags: android, variables, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-toast

When I click on an item (course name) within the recycleview, it takes me to a new activity. However, I only need 2 courses to be working for now. For the rest of the items in the recycleview, I don`t want to add any target activity. Instead of that, I just want to add a toast message saying "This function is not yet available" for example. How do I do these things?

Data class:

```
data class CourseList(
    val courseTitle: String,
    val courseType: String,
    val courseLength: String,
    val target: Class<out Activity>
)
```

CourseListActivityHE:

```
CourseListActivityHe : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.course_list)

        val course = listOf(
            CourseList("BSc (Hons) Networking", "Type: Full/Part Time", "Length: 3/6 Years", CourseViewActivityHe1::class.java),
            CourseList("BSc (Hons) Software Engineering", "Type: Full/Part Time", "Length: 3/6 Years", CourseListActivityHe::class.java),
            CourseList("BSc (Hons) Civil Engineering PM", "Type: Full/Part Time", "Length: 3/6 Years", CourseListActivityHe::class.java),
            CourseList("Level 4 Electrical Engineering", "Type: Full/Part Time", "Length: 1/2 Years", CourseListActivityHe::class.java),
            CourseList("Level 4 Mechanical Engineering", "Type: Full/Part Time", "Length: 1/2 Years", CourseListActivityHe::class.java),
            CourseList("Level 5 Electrical Engineering", "Type: Full/Part Time", "Length: 2/4 Years", CourseListActivityHe::class.java),
            CourseList("Level 5 Mechanical Engineering", "Type: Full/Part Time", "Length: 2/4 Years", CourseListActivityHe::class.java),
            CourseList("BSc (Hons) Ophthalmic Dispensing", "Type: Full/Part Time", "Length: 3/6 Years", CourseListActivityHe::class.java),
            CourseList("FdSc Ophthalmic Dispensing", "Type: Full/Part Time", "Length: 2/4 Years", CourseListActivityHe::class.java)
        )

        list_of_course.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@CourseListActivityHe)
            adapter = CourseListAdapter(course){
                startActivity(Intent(this@CourseListActivityHe, it.target))
            }
        }
```

CourseListAdapter (if needed):

```
class CourseListAdapter( val course: List<CourseList>, val courseClicked: (CourseList) -> Unit):
RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.course_list_activity, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(layoutView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = course.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val cours = course[position]

        with(holder.view) {
            setOnClickListener{
                (courseClicked)(cours)
        }
    }

        holder.view.courseTitle.text = "${cours.courseTitle}"
        holder.view.courseType.text = "${cours.courseType}"
        holder.view.courseLength.text = "${cours.courseLength}"
    }

    class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a default value to constructor parameters.

```
data class CourseList(
        val courseTitle: String = "",
        val courseType: String = "",
        val courseLength: String,
        val target: Class<out Activity>
    )
```

Better Example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println("person1 is instantiated")
    val person1 = Person("joe", 25)

    println("person2 is instantiated")
    val person2 = Person("Jack")

    println("person3 is instantiated")
    val person3 = Person()
}

class Person(_firstName: String = "UNKNOWN", _age: Int = 0) {
    val firstName = _firstName.capitalize()
    var age = _age

    // initializer block
    init {
        println("First Name = $firstName")
        println("Age = $age\n")
    }
}
```

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
data class CourseList(
    val courseTitle: String = "",
    val courseType: String = "Type: Full/Part Time",
    val courseLength: String = "",
    val target: Class<out Activity> = CourseListActivityHe::class.java
)

or

so only 2 courseTitle and courseLength is required

data class CourseList(
    val courseTitle: String,
    val courseType: String = "Type: Full/Part Time",
    val courseLength: String,
    val target: Class<out Activity> = CourseListActivityHe::class.java
)
```

In that way it will make all of the variables optional

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you show me how to set course1 and course2 buttons to open up different activities? Because the code above will apply the same target activity to every single item (course) within the recycleview, but I want them to open a different activity. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I mean, I was able to direct each item to a different activity, but when I leave the target variable empty, it still takes me to CourseListActivityHE, which is defined within CourseList.

Comment: just supply 4 params it will still be accepted if you want to modify the activity

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't fix this issue. When I leave the target activity's space empty within the listOf, there isn't any errors. But when I run it, that specific item with no target will take me to to activity mentioned within the data class. "val target: Class<out Activity> = CourseListActivityHe::class.java" How do I make the target optional as well, without mentioning any activity name within the data class?

Comment: You can declare them as: CourseList(courseTitle="BSc (Hons) Networking",courseType="Length: 3/6 Years", target=CourseViewActivityHe1::class.java)